# Golang RedirectHandler() returns interface, ends up with *http.redirectHandler

Tags: http, go, pointers

Please do not be aggressive with my post, I am trying to learn Go, but facing some challenges in my understanding.

This is my sample code:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "reflect"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        mux := http.NewServeMux()

        rh := http.RedirectHandler("http://example.org", 307)
        fmt.Println("The type of the object, returned by the RedirectHandler is")
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(rh))
        fmt.Println("End with type observation")
        mux.Handle("/foo", rh)

        log.Println("Listening ...")
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", mux)
}
```

My questions are:

1. RedirectHandler returns a Handler interface, is this a common pattern and what is the benefit ?
2. Does that mean that the inside the function you schould have a struct that implements that interface and then return the struct ? If not, how in the world do we return an interface, as essentially it's just a set of non-implemented methods ?
3. If you run my code, you would see that the type of the variable 'rh' is *http.redirectHandler. For such a pointer I am not able to find anything in the http package, so we started from 'returns an interface' to end up with 'here's your pointer, that does not exists in the doc'.
4. Those are just my confusing thoughts, I would appreciate comments who want to help me with my confusion.

Comment: I recommend you take the tour of Go (if you've already taken it, it seems you need the refresher). `RedirectHandler` returns a handler you can just pass to `mux.Handler`, there's nothing else for you to implement. As for `redirectHandler`, it's not an exported type but it does implement the handler interface: https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?#L2166.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. I remember the old simple Java question, how upvoted they were. Now when a random person does not understand something and post his simple question, he gets immediately down voted. I do not care about upvotes or anything, but it's just repelling.

Comment: Perhaps, but your question shows a lack of research. The people active on the [go] tag tend to frown upon that.

Comment: 1. NA. This is done sometimes, sometimes not. This is like asking  "is returning a int common and what are the benefits". Interfaces are normal things in Go. 2. Any thing satisfying an interface can be returned as such an interface. This can be a struct or some other type. 3. You will not learn anything from peaking inside that interface. As you noted this is a private (unexported) implementation detail which is of no concern to you. 4. You are  not going to learn much from this kind of experiments. Go's type system is pretty simple and just learn it (via the Tour of Go).

Comment: @Marc, I did the research and was still confused. Following the 'research pattern', it's better never to ask, just keep researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. RedirectHandler returns a Handler interface, is this a common pattern and what is the benefit?

While there is a rule of thumb to return concrete types instead of interfaces (often stated as "Accept interfaces return structs"), it is sometimes desirable to hide the implementation, for any number of reasons. One of them is to be free to change the implementation in any way in future versions of a package. Another is to prevent misuse of the return value; accessing struct fields concurrently, for instance.

Making all these functions (RedirectHandler, NotFoundHandler, TimeoutHandler, etc.) return http.Handler also makes them easily discoverable in the docs: they all appear together as constructors for http.Handler instead of scattered around in the list of functions. I'm assuming (!) that may have played a role when deciding to do it this way, but you'd have to ask the authors (you can do this on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts)).

> 2. Does that mean that [RedirectHandler returns] a struct that implements that interface?

Maybe. It can also return any other type that implements the interface, although it is indeed a struct type in Go 1.15. But that can change, precisely because the function returns an interface instead of a concrete type.

> 3. If you run my code, you would see that the type of the variable 'rh' is *http.redirectHandler. For such a pointer I am not able to find anything in the http package.

The docs for unexported identifiers are not rendered by default (because you can't use them anyway). Add `m=all` to the query string to show them: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/?m=all#redirectHandler